# ld.so issue after upgrading Ubuntu to release 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, shared-library

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 22.04, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored
```

Comment: Where do you see this error, and when? What does the error stop you from doing? Do you set `LD_PRELOAD` somewhere?